# Macro to split data at specific element and paste it's respective values in next columns

Tags: vba, excel

As shown below in image2 I have 3 sets of data having same elements in column1(order could be different) with different values in column2.I need a macro which will split the data at specific element(**A**) and paste the values of the respective element in column3..column4..column5 accordingly as shown in image1.

Here is the Expected output:

[image: expected output]

This is my current input data:

[image: Input data]

Comment: Please show what code you have already done

Comment: please post data as formatted text, People will be more likely to answer your question. also post your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. This assumes there is an A in every section and is used as the section divider

```
Public Sub Generate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim c, key
    Dim NoOfSets As Long
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, 2))
    NoOfSets = Application.CountIf(rng, "A")
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        ReDim tmp(1 To NoOfSets)

        If Not Dict.exists(rng.Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then
            tmp(j) = rng.Cells(i, 2).Value2
            Dict.Add key:=rng.Cells(i, 1).Value2, Item:=tmp
        Else
            If rng.Cells(i, 1) = "A" Then j = j + 1
            tmp = Dict(rng.Cells(i, 1).Value2)
            tmp(j) = rng.Cells(i, 2).Value2
            Dict(rng.Cells(i, 1).Value2) = tmp
        End If
    Next i

    j = 0
    With Cells(1, 4)
        For Each key In Dict.keys
            .Offset(j, 0) = key
            Range(.Offset(j, 1), .Offset(j, UBound(Dict(key)))) = Dict(key)
            j = j + 1
        Next key
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow..that worked excellent,this is what I was looking for.Thanks a lot Tom :)